# How to show an activity without showing parent activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I have an `SMSReceiver` class, which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. Once SMS is received, I create notification. When it is clicked, I start my own (not main!) activity - `DialogActivity`:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, DialogActivity.class);
...
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent mPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context,
    mNotificationId,
    mIntent,
    0
);          
mBuilder.setContentIntent(mPendingIntent);
```

However, it is always shown on top of the main activity. So, if I call `finish` from the `DialogActivity`, then the main activity is shown. How could I avoid that?

`DialogActivity` class looks like below:

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog); // android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

        Button dialogBtnNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_no);

        dialogBtnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish(); // close this activity
            }
    ...
```

and manifest file:

```
   <activity
        android:name="my.package.DialogActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
```

Comment: post the whole code of DialogActivity.class

Comment: change context to getapplicationbasecontext()

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work but have you tried also adding the `Flag` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`?

Comment: No, the `Context` is correct

Comment: @codeMagic, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't help...

Comment: You could set a flag in `onCreate()` of the `LoginActivity` that calls `finish()` before `setContentView()` if it is opened from `DialogActivity`. Not the most elegant way but I'm not sure what else right now

Answer (score 1):

Use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to clear the current task before starting the new activity.

The problem with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK- from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK):

> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
>   you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started;
>   instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the
>   screen with the state it was last in.

This flag is available in api 11 or later and in the v4 support library.

Comment: Looks like it will work with new APIs only - `Field requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.content.Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Comment: So the behavior you want is to go back to the home screen after the dialog activity?

Comment: Looks like it is in the v4 support library...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in `DialogActivity` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`. It will be correctly works.